Finding angles in a convex quadrilateral, given only the lengths and angle between opposing sides
I'm currently struggling with finding the angles of a quadrilateral and can't seem to come up with a solution.
This image shows a visual representation of my problem.
I am trying to mathematically calculate the shown quadrilateral but all the other instructions for finding the rest of the angles assume you know the angle between adjacent sides, whereas I only know the angle between opposing sides.
Modelling up the shape in CAD software leads to a 'fully constrained' quadrilateral, which makes me think there must be a single solution that can be calculated mathematically.
The quadrilateral is not cyclical.
Thank you for any help!

Have you tried labelling the sides adjacent to the angle and applying the Cosine Rule in the smaller and larger triangles? It’s numerically messy but you will obtain a linear relationship between these unknown sides and hence be able to calculate them. The Sine Rule can then be used to calculate the angles.

Thanks for the answer, I think I can see what you mean, but I was unable to find the right equations. Would you be able to lead me in the right direction a bit more?
I take it your suggestion is to split the triangle as shown in this image?

Quinn's idea is  to solve the two cosine rules $b^2=a'^2+c'^2-2a'c'\cos \theta_M$ and $d^2=(a+a')^2+(c+c')^2-2(a+a')(c+c')\cos\theta_M$ where $a=280$, $b=290$, $c=120$, $d=470$, $\theta_M=50^\circ$, $M$ the point at the given angle, the first (smaller) triangle BMC, the second (larger) triangle AMD, $a'$ the distance from B to M and $c'$ the distance from C to M. This is 2 equations with two unknowns $a'$ and $c'$.

@R.J.Mathar thanks, and further to this, my point is that you can subtract these equations to eliminate all three quadratic terms in $a’$ and $c’$ , i.e $a’^2$, $b’^2$ and $a’b’$, leaving a linear equation between them…

The image defines a quadrangle with corners A, B, C and D in clockwise order.
The 4 known side lengths are $a=|AB|$, $b=|BC|$, $c=|CD|$ and $d=|DA|$.
Denote the angles inside the quadrangle at the 4 corners by $\theta_{A,B,C,D}$.
Denote the length of the diagonal AC by $e$ and the length of the diagonal BD by $f$.
The notation is the same as in Solving 4 unknown angles in a Quadrilateral given 4 sides and a constraint
The angle sum inside a quadrangle is
$$
\theta_A+\theta_B+\theta_C+\theta_D=2\pi.
$$
There is a also a point where the extensions of sides AB and CD meet at a known angle $\theta_M=50^\circ$,
which we may call $M$. Because AMD is a triangle, the sum of its interior angles is
$$
\theta_A+\theta_M+\theta_D=\pi.
$$
Mixing this into the previous equation yields 2 angle sums
$$
\theta_A+\theta_D=\pi-\theta_M;
\theta_B+\theta_C=\pi+\theta_M.
$$
The cosine rules inside the 4 triangles defined by the two diagonals and edges
of the quadrangle are
$$
e^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_B;
$$
$$
e^2=c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta_D;
$$
$$
f^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\theta_C;
$$
$$
f^2=a^2+d^2-2ad\cos\theta_A.
$$
Eliminating $e^2$ and $f^2$ in these 4 equations yields
$$
a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_B=
c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta_D;
$$
$$
b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\theta_C=
a^2+d^2-2ad\cos\theta_A.
$$
Elimination of $\theta_C$ and $\theta_D$ via the angle sums gives
2 equations for 2 unknown angles $\theta_{A,B}$:
$$
a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_B=
c^2+d^2-2cd\cos(\pi-\theta_M-\theta_A);
$$
$$
b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(\pi+\theta_M-\theta_B)=
a^2+d^2-2ad\cos\theta_A.
$$
$$
 a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_B=
c^2+d^2+2cd\cos(\theta_M+\theta_A);
$$
$$
b^2+c^2+2bc\cos(-\theta_M+\theta_B)=
a^2+d^2-2ad\cos\theta_A.
$$
This coupled nonlinear equation for $\theta_{A,B}$ is difficult to solve.
Quinn's method in the comments yields a simpler way: Consider the triangle BMC with
side lengths $a'$, $c'$ and $b$ and the triangle $AMD$ with side
lengths $a+a'$, $c+c'$ and $d$. The 2 cosine rules are
$$
(*)\quad b^2=a'^2+c'^2-2a'c'\cos\theta_M;
$$
$$
d^2=(a+a')^2+(c+c')^2-2(a+a')(c+c')\cos\theta_M
$$
Expansion of the 2nd equation  and subtracting both equations yields
a linear relation
$$
(**)\quad b^2-d^2+a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\theta_M
= 
(-2a+2c\cos\theta_M)a'+(-2c+2a\cos\theta_M)c'
$$
with coefficients
$$z\equiv b^2-d^2+a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\theta_M;$$
$$x \equiv -2a+2c\cos\theta_m;$$
$$y \equiv -2c+2a\cos\theta_m;$$
such that
$$
z = xa'+yc'
$$
Inserting this back into the quadratic equation (*) yields
quadratic equation for $a'$:
$$
(y^2+x^2+2yx\cos\theta_m)a'^2 -2z(x+y\cos \theta_m)a'-(by)^2+z^2=0;
$$
$$
4\sin^2\theta_m (a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\theta_m)a'^2
+4a\sin^2\theta_m(z-2ac\cos\theta_m) a'+(z-by)(z+by)=0.
$$
For the example $a=280$, $b=290$, $c=120$, $d=470$, $\theta_m=5\pi/18$ this yields
$$
116436 a'^2-0.57308\times 10^8 a'+0.639277\times 10^{10}=0
$$
which has the 2 solutions
$$
a' = 170.8711, 321.314
$$
The smaller $a'$ leads to a negative $c'$ via (**), which we drop. Therefore
$$
a' = 321.314, c'=359.881
$$
Applying the cosine rule to the triangle AMD gives
$$
(c+c')^2=(a+a')^2+d^2-2(a+a')d\cos\theta_A
$$
therefore $\cos\theta_a=0.623089$, $\theta_A=0.8981094=51.45787^\circ$

Thank you for this, however my knowledge of imaginary number equations is very limited so unfortunately I can't follow the last few steps. I will try to do some learning in order to understand a bit better, but if you had the time to explain a bit more that would be much appreciated. Even an example of how to solve given the numbers in my question would be fantastic. Thanks again!

I am trying my best to leave around a simple answer.
I'm applying basic law of cosines:-
$$BD^2=AB^2+DA^2-2ABDA\cos \angle BAD$$
$$BD^2=BC^2+CD^2-2BCCD\cos \angle BCD$$
Equating these, we get :-
$$BC^2+CD^2-2BCCD\cos \angle BCD=AB^2+DA^2-2ABDA\cos \angle BAD$$
Putting your values, I get
$$2632 \cos \angle BAD - 696 \cos \angle BCD = 2008...(i)$$
We do the same for the diagonal $AC$, to get
$$AB^2+BC^2-2ABBC\cos \angle ABC = DA^2+CD^2-2DACD \cos \angle CDA $$
To get
$$1128 \cos \angle CDA -1624 \cos \angle ABC=728 $$
Now from your diagram, we get to know $ cos \angle CDA= \cos (130°-\angle DAB)$
and $ cos \angle ABC = \cos (230°-\angle BCD)$
So
$$1128\cos (130°-\angle DAB)-1624 \cos (230°-\angle BCD)=728...(ii)$$
You need a calc to solve this. It's super tedious without them.
